# How can I get the autoload.php file for Google Plus quickstart php example?

Tags: google-plus, composer-php

[image]

I'm using the official code example given by Google in their documentation.  The `signin.php` file that runs first has a line of code:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

But there is no `autoload.php` file provided, and none got created during the installation.    This is the code I'm trying to use:

[Google+ API Quickstart in PHP](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-php)

I *can* find info on autoloading for `Composer`, which is used as a dependency manager.

> Composer finds out which versions of which packages need to be
>   installed, and installs them (meaning it downloads them into your
>   project).

From Composer's documentation: [Autoloading done by Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#autoloading)

> Besides downloading the library, Composer also prepares an autoload
>   file that's capable of autoloading all of the classes in any of the
>   libraries that it downloads. To use it, just add the following line to
>   your code's bootstrap process:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Composer's documentation states that all that is needed to get started is a `composer.json` file.  I do have that.

```
{
    "name": "googleplus/quickstart",
    "description": "This quick-start app is built in PHP and lets you get started with the Google+ platform in a few minutes.",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "google/google-api-php-client",
                "version": "0.6.2",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/files/google-api-php-client-0.6.2.tar.gz",
                    "type": "tar"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "classmap": [
                        "src/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "1.0.*@dev",
        "twig/twig": ">=1.8,<2.0-dev",
        "google/google-api-php-client": "0.6.2"
    }
}
```

It looks like the JSON file is saying that this app needs the Google tar file, and that Silex, Twig, and the Google API PHP are required.  But how the JSON file is used meet those requirements, I have no idea.

For the installation, I ran:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

on the command line and got a msg that Composer was successfully installed.  So I'm assuming that isn't a problem.

Let's see.  I'm going through the installation process again:  I ran:

`php composer.phar install`

and got this error:

Failed to clone https://github.com/fabpot/Silex.git, git was not found, check that it is installed in your PATH env.
`git` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or bath file.

It looks like the code is mistakenly putting `.git` at the end of the URL.  That's probably why the `php composer.phar install` is not getting the Silex files and putting them into my `silex` folder.  I may need to download the silex files manually.  Okay, I just manually installed all the `silex` files, and that did nothing.  Installing the `silex` micro framework obviously doesn't create a `autoload.php` file, so you can't run what isn't there.

I have no idea what is supposed to go into that `autoload.php` file.  I'd try to learn what is supposed to go in there, and code it myself, but I can't even find a clue to get me going in the right direction.  Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try again to run the command `php composer.phar install --prefer-dist` - with that flag enabled Composer tries to download ZIP files of that version instead of using the command line version of Git (which seems to not be installed on your machine).

In other news, I think you can safely switch from that development version of Silex to a stable one. Remove that "@dev" tag from the Silex version requirement. There are released versions 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1.0, 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 - one of these should work.

Comment: Thanks, that did create an `autoload.php` file in the vendor folder.  Okay, I'm not getting an error for the autoload line now.  Excellent.  So, does this mean that the `composer.phar` file needs `git` available to the command line in order to run?

Comment: If Composer must access a repository, it will need the appropriate tools to do so. It can access Git, SVN and Mercurial by using their commandline tools. These must be installed if Composer does not know about a download source.